# Why does this schematic have 4 diodes plus a quadruple one?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, diodes, circuits

The schematic can be found [here.](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/master/schematic/LilyGo-SIM800C-20200630.pdf)

On the sim card section it has 4 diodes (ULC0511C) plus a quadruple (SMF05C).

Shouldn't it be either the 4 of them or the quadruple one?

Why use the 4 ones plus the quadruple?

[image]

Comment: I haven't checked their datasheets, but: Possibly protecting against different things?

Comment: Those are TVS (Transient Voltage Suppression) diodes, they are there to protect against over-voltages.

Comment: @MarcusMüller both the 4s and the quadruple are connected on the same nets.. if they protect against different things then why didn't the author use the most restricting one, if that makes any sense at all..?

Comment: @Vinzent sure but why the author is also using the quadruple one? shouldn't it be either the 4s or the quadruple?

Comment: Hard to say, at first glance it seems redundant but it might be that one acts faster than the other and/or one can take more power.. It can sometimes be hard to properly protect a circuit against both large transients and fast esd.

Answer (score 1):

I only see one 6-pin package on the board, and that's the dual transistor (H3).

So I think that two were allowed for and only one made it to production (there's no unpopulated footprint either). I don't have one in front of me, that's just based on photographs.

Comment: copy that. however I think I couldn't find a photo of the version with chip 800c. only with chip 800L which is different PCB.. but thanks!

Comment: @Sphero This is more of a comment